Neighbor's car started vibrating at low speeds (25-35 mph). CV boot is leaking grease, could it be a bad axle?
He says it's been leaking grease from the boot for a month or two now.
Vibration lessens as speed picks up.
2007 Camry, 160k.
Could it be unbalanced wheels, alignment, bad axle?


He says it's been leaking grease from the boot for a month or two now.

That needs to be fixed right now.
A damaged CV joint boot will contaminate the grease, which will destroy the CV joint rapidly. There's no time to lose.
The symptoms appear when driving the car in curves. If this hasn't happened yet, it might be possible to save the CV joint by replacing the grease and the boot.
However, if your vibration happens at slow speeds and lessens when speed picks up, and is not limited to curves, then CV joint is not the likely cause. But the CV joint should be fixed soon.

This answer is probably correct.  However, a similar vibration  in our Mitsubishi has a at around 35 MPH was due to the transmission.  Ours went away if we changed to manual and did the shifting ourselves.
